# Most and Least popular primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Example**

Denote $p_{1},p_{3},p_{7},p_{9}$ as the number of primes ending in $1,3,7,9$ for some $n$.

Ran a loop for $n = [3,...,1000000000]$ with $50847532$ primes found.
As each prime was encountered, the popularity was calculated

**Most Popular** = $max(p_{1},p_{3},p_{7},p_{9})$

**Least Popular** = $min(p_{1},p_{3},p_{7},p_{9})$

The results show $3,7$ vying to be most popular while $1,9$ least popular.

[image: most]
[image: least]

**Questions**

How should one interpret these results?

Maybe as $n\to\infty$

- $p_{1},p_{9}$ will never be most popular.
- $p_{3},p_{7}$ will never be least popular.

However, I was not expecting that bias among $p_{1},p_{3},p_{7},p_{9}$.
Shouldn't the popularity be more evenly spread among the primes?

Comment: Remarkably, in view of your experiment, they really are "evenly spread" in some technical sense: this is [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), which says that if $a$ and $d$ are coprime, then there are infinitely many primes of the form $a + k d$, and moreover (the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions) the number of primes up to $X$ of these forms grows like $\frac{X}{\phi(d) \log X}$, independent of $a$. In your case, take $d = 10$ and $a = 1, 3, 7, 9$.

Comment: The final digits have the same proportion in the limit, but it's still possible that the differences of counts have a bias...

Comment: See also [Prime number race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_race) for some interesting references on this phenomenon.

Comment: Terry Tao gives a brief explanation of this (called the Chebyshev bias) at the beginning of [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/biases-between-consecutive-primes/):  the bias should be negligible if you include prime _powers_ as well as actual primes, and in your case 1 and 9 suffer more from excluding the powers because squares can't end in 3 or 7.  But the magnitude of the bias is small enough that it's expected that 1 and 9 will be most popular a small positive proportion of the time.

Comment: Interesting, so the 'small positive proportion' for $1,9$ being most popular never reaches $0$.  Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this is a special case of the Cheboratov density theorem

Comment: What do you mean with "popular" ? If it means how often the primes occur, then "frequency" would be much less confusing.

Comment: On the long run, each residue class produces the same fraction of primes , despite Chebyshev's bias.